# login page in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

please help, Im always having trouble having to go through all this stuff. When all I need is for phpmyadmin to have a login form so that I could input the password and username.
I don't need all the stuff included in this documentation. Is there a tutorial for beginners on how to have a login form in phpmyadmin. Documentations like this really sucks.
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#config

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if you want to make a login from a form, go into config.inc.php and change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Now restart the appache server and if you goto phpmyadmin it will prompt you for a username and a password.

Comment: As per wamp server 2.5, just comment the "$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';" line and uncomment "$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';" line instead of changing config to cookie which is not wrong by the way. I just did this and got the login page and after logging in I got an option to change my password too.

Answer (score 1):

you have to modify your config file by default you have no password for the phpmyadmin in wamp
(c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin/config.php) and change these

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

The login form for phpmyadmin is usually at http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

How did you install it? From your package manager or from the source?

**Edit**

Well, I just installed it and I can access no problem.

Make sure the services are run (From the screenshot, run "Start All Services") and you can click on the phpmyadmin link

Comment: downloaded it from here: http://www.wampserver.com/en/ then installed it. I just clicked next next and next without configuring anything

Comment: i always get this error whenever I have put a password using phpmyadmin by going to privileges(root) http://i49.tinypic.com/ot1478.jpg

Comment: From my <install_dir>/apps/phpmyadmin3.2.0.1/ , in the config.inc, do you have $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true ? If not, set it to true, restart services and try.